# Randomize Quiz Answers Order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a quiz that randomizes the quiz answers order; however, I'm stuck on how to make sure I know which one is the correct answer, and how to format it using letters (e.g. A), B), C) ). I'm using a text file for questions and answers.

```
for line in file:
    line = line.strip("\n")
    line=line.split(",")
    question=line[0]
    ans=line[1:QuestionAmount]
    random.shuffle(ans)
    print(question)
    print(*ans)
```

For example

A) answer3
B) correctans
C) answer1

Then next time

A) correctans
B) answer1
C) answer3

How do I know what letter the correct answer will be in?

Comment: is the correct answer always in the same position in your text file (e.g. the first item after the question) ?

Comment: Yes its always the first item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

line = "Question?,answer3,answer1,correctans,answer4"

line = line.strip("\n")
line=line.split(",")

question=line[0]
ans=line[1:]

print(question)

random.shuffle(ans)
idx = 0

for a in ans :
    a = chr(ord('A')+idx) + ')' + a
    ans[idx] = a
    idx += 1
print(*ans)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works; however I wish to have an input where the user enters A B C OR D so how do I know which letter will have the correct answer and how to compare it to the input?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the answer to the file on the same line as your question, so when you are reading the file you can also read the answer with it then do a compare to see if the users answer is correct

`A) answer3 B) correctans C) answer1 Ans:B`

Comment: But the answers will shuffle all the time so ans will not always be B

Answer (score 0):

Simply begin the correct answer with a marker, such as an asterisk.
When you print the choices for each question, strip any leading asterisk off the front of the choice.  For isntance, alter you file to read

```
answer1, *correctans, answer3
```

Just before you print, it may appear as

```
["answer1", "*correctans", "answer1"]
```

And you print each element with `strip('*')`